# Azure App Service with third Party SSL Auto renewal

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, auto-renewing

I have a Azure app service which uses Godaddy SSL certificate. And in Godaddy Auto renewal is enabled. But everytime the SSL certificate expires i have to manually download the certificate from godaddy and convert into .pfx file to upload it on azure. Is there any way to auto renew the certificate on Azure without uploading .pfx?

Comment: I haven't find one yet. And it sucks

Answer (score 0):

If you have not performed domain verification yet, you must do so before renewing your App Service certificate. If you do not, you will not be able to renew your certificate as it will fail to validate domain ownership. App Service certificates do not automate domain verification.

[image]

For more information please follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#renew-certificate).